# Does WPF embed full size image into output?

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a WPF application that includes buttons with PNG images.  The actual images get scaled by grid control inside the button to about 32 pixels or so (depending on button size).  At the same time my original artwork created in Photoshop is 250x250 pixels in size.

Currently I create artwork in Photoshop, add it to my WPF project as a resource, and have WPF automatically scale it to the button size.

Here's my question - if my original image is 250x250 pixels, and WPF squeezes it into a button so that it is only 32x32 pixels, does my output file contain the 250x250 image, or the 32x32 image?

I'm asking because if the app performance is going to be negatively affected by the original image size, I'd rather just scale it in Photoshop myself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it will include the full file, because it can't recognize that it might not be shown larger at runtime.  You can check this by decompiling your program using [ILSpy](http://wiki.sharpdevelop.net/ILSpy.ashx).

Comment: Thanks for the info.  I was hoping this wouldn't be the case. Gotta wait 10 minutes to accept your answer.